# C# Filter datagridview based on multiple selections of listBox

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, listbox, filtering

When the user clicks on one of my datagridview's columns and chooses to filter, a window pops up with a listbox which is populated with that column's values (not repetitive- meaning if there are 5 0's it is only shown once).

This is the initialization of the popup window.

```
public partial class ComboBoxFilter : Form
{

    DataGridView Dgv;
    DataGridViewColumn Col;
    DataView View;
    string CName;

    public ComboBoxFilter(DataGridView dgv, DataGridViewColumn col, DataView view, string colName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dgv = dgv;
        Col = col;
        View = view;
        CName = colName;
        listBox1.ValueMember = col.DataPropertyName;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = col.DataPropertyName;
        DataTable dt = view.ToTable(true, new string[] { col.DataPropertyName });
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = col.DataPropertyName;
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

When user selects one value from listbox and pushes OK button:

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)Dgv.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", CName, listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        Dgv.DataSource = bs;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Where CName is the column's to be filtered name.

This works great.

However now I would like to allow multiselect property on my listbox, so that if the user selects multiple values, I can filter for that. How can I do this? Is it necessary to use "OR" like I've seen in some examples?

Comment: Moving controls into a forms constructor gives me the creeps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DataView.RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, you can use `OR` or `IN` operators to build the filter criteria, with IMO the later being more appropriate for this scenario.

So the code could be something like this

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selection = string.Join(",", listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
        .Select(item => "'" + listBox1.GetItemText(item) + "'").ToArray());
    var filter = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0 ? string.Empty : 
        listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 1 ? string.Format("{0} = {1}", CName, selection) :
        string.Format("{0} IN ({1})", CName, selection);

    var bs = (BindingSource)Dgv.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = filter;
    this.Close();
}
```